# Como usar o comando break dentro de dois laços no Ruby?

Tags: ruby, break

Quando for executado o comando "break" no "if" tem jeito de sair do laço interno e o externo ? não apenas de um ?

```
while (i < maior) do
  if tam1>tam2
     for i2 in 0 .. tam2 do
        if(palavra1[i]==palavra2[i2])
           iguais = palavra1[i2]
           posicao = i
           break #Quero que saia desse laço e do outro
        end
     end
  else
      for i2 in 0 .. tam1 do
          if(palavra2[i]==palavra1[i2])
            iguais = palavra2[i2]
            posicao = i
            break #Quero que saia desse laço e do outro
          end
        end
     end
   i+=1
  end
```

Comment: Acredito que você possa fazer isso fazendo uso de uma variável de controle. Basicamente, antes de efetuar o break em definitivo, deixe essa variavel num estado "verdadeiro", e dê um break no mais superficial. O próximo deve analisar essa variável e executar break se ela ser true.

Comment: Eu fiz uma variável de controle e deu certo, mas não entendi o seu raciocínio  "deixe essa variável num estado "verdadeiro", e dê um break no mais superficial. O próximo deve analisar essa variável e executar break se ela ser true."

Comment: Basicamente, se for fazer um break em todos os loops, ela fica verdadeira e cada loop faz um break. Caso não, apenas o primeiro break é executado, pois ela fica falsa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que a solução mais simples no seu caso, é satisfazer a condição do `while`:

```
if(palavra1[i]==palavra2[i2])
  iguais = palavra1[i2]
  posicao = i
  i = maior # sairemos dos laços aqui!
end
```

Dito isso, vi uma solução [numa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352120/how-to-break-outer-cycle-in-ruby) que me agradou bastante - você pode criar um bloco `catch` ao invés de usar o `while`:

```
catch:encerrar do
  5.times do |a|
    3.times do |b|
      throw :encerrar if a+b > 3
      puts "#{a}, #{b}\n"
    end
  end
end
```

`throw` interrompe a execução do bloco inteiro, assim que a condição `if` é satisfeita.

> Resultado:

[image: resultado da execução do programa]